# Flushing linux DNS from JAVA

Tags: linux, dns, cloud

We have a RC module that gets dropped into our cloud servers during hot deployment. To that end, I need a way to flush the DNS programmatically from within JAVA. The best solution that I can think of is to just have java fire an external shell script, however I'm not having any luck. I've tried the "normal" procedures to an avail:

1) restarting nscd service (not installed in these servers)
 
2) /etc/init.d/networking restart (no effect)
 
3) /etc/init.d/dns-clean start (no effect)

Anyone have any more suggestions?

(NOTE: this is a re-word of a previous post that must have been determined as being "non-development" related...)

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is JVM implementation dependent. On Oracle JDK, you need to set the `networkaddress.cache.ttl` and `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` *security* properties (in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security`). The factory default is to cache positive answers forever.

AFAIK there is no way to flush the cache at runtime.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Comment: Thanks Wil. It doesn't look like I can pull off exactly what I'm trying to do, but the settings you pointed out should give me a little bit more wiggle room to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 6 (Sun/Apple) and Java 7+ (OpenJDK), the default value for `networkaddress.cache.ttl` is **30 seconds** (specified in `sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy`) assuming there is no security manager installed (via `-Djava.security.manager` or `System.setSecurityManager`).

Meanwhile, the default value for `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` is **10 seconds** (specified in `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security`).

Web servers (e.g. [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Configuring_Tomcat_With_A_SecurityManager)) may install a security manager on startup, in which case the JVM (at least those I've mentioned) will cache positive lookups forever [by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html#nct).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to natively call (JNI) to res_init() from Java:

*ResInitLoader.java*

```
package my.pkg;
public class ResInitLoader {
    static {
            System.loadLibrary("ResInit");
    }
    public static native int resInit();
}
```

*ResInit.c*

```
#include <resolv.h>
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_my_pkg_ResInitLoader_resInit (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
   return res_init();
}
```